# Error running hadoop job from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am facing some issues while trying to launch a mapreduce job on our Hadoop cluster from eclipse. I have added a folder named "conf" as a class folder and under that folder, I have imported the "core-site.xml", "hdfs-site.xml", "mapred-site.xml" and "hbase-site.xml". My hadoop cluster runs Hadoop 0.20.205.0, HBase-0.94.1. We are able to successfully submit the jobs to the cluser using "hadoop jar" command. Since this is very cumbersome, I want to setup eclipse such that I could submit the Hadoop jobs to the cluster by just running the program.

After I added the required dependencies to the project, I am getting the following exception when I run the example "PiEstimator.java" (of Hadoop-0.20.205.0).

Number of Maps  = 4
Samples per Map = 4
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.create(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, short, long)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.create(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.create(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.<init>(DFSClient.java:3245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:713)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:182)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:555)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:892)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:284)
at com.amazon.seo.mapreduce.examples.PiEstimator.estimate(PiEstimator.java:265)
at com.amazon.seo.mapreduce.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:325)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at com.amazon.seo.mapreduce.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:333)
```

Can you please help me understand what part of my setup is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve this issue?
I've resolved similar error with ClassDefinition as follows:
Create Jar as a Runnable Java File (File >> Export >> Runnable Java File)
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH =

This will make hadoop to pickup the correct class from your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe that you will have to upgrade Hadoop's version to at least 2.5.0